# UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying Hadoop 2.5.1 WordCount tutorial in Windows 7

Tags: java, hadoop, windows-7

I am trying to work through the Hadoop MapReduce "WordCount" tutorial [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html). I've copied the source code file exactly as is (except I omitted the package declaration), but I don't think my problem has anything to do with the actual program code itself and is rather a problem with the way Hadoop is set up on my computer. Here is the command I've given (from the hadoop-2.5.1/bin directory):

`hadoop jar ../../TestProgram/HadoopTest.jar WordCount ../../TestProgram/input ../../TestProgram/output2`

The exception itself is:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z`

And here is the output in its entirety:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
14/10/31 13:52:30 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/10/31 13:52:30 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
14/10/31 13:52:30 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
14/10/31 13:52:30 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
14/10/31 13:52:30 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
14/10/31 13:52:31 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
14/10/31 13:52:31 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
14/10/31 13:52:31 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local600999744_0001
14/10/31 13:52:31 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-Kenny/mapred/staging/Kenny600999744/.staging/job_local600999744_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
14/10/31 13:52:31 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-Kenny/mapred/staging/Kenny600999744/.staging/job_local600999744_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
14/10/31 13:52:31 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-Kenny/mapred/staging/Kenny600999744/.staging/job_local600999744_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:977)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskChecker.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirAccess(DiskChecker.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager.setup(LocalDistributedCacheManager.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:833)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
14/10/31 13:52:31 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\tmp\hadoop-Kenny\hadoop-unjar2075153006497925230\lib\hadoop-common-2.5.1.jar]: it still exists.
14/10/31 13:52:31 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\tmp\hadoop-Kenny\hadoop-unjar2075153006497925230\lib\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.5.1.jar]: it still exists.
14/10/31 13:52:31 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\tmp\hadoop-Kenny\hadoop-unjar2075153006497925230\lib\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.5.1.jar]: it still exists.
14/10/31 13:52:31 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\tmp\hadoop-Kenny\hadoop-unjar2075153006497925230\lib\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.1.jar]: it still exists.
14/10/31 13:52:31 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\tmp\hadoop-Kenny\hadoop-unjar2075153006497925230\lib\hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.5.1.jar]: it still exists.
14/10/31 13:52:31 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\tmp\hadoop-Kenny\hadoop-unjar2075153006497925230\lib\hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.5.1.jar]: it still exists.
14/10/31 13:52:31 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\tmp\hadoop-Kenny\hadoop-unjar2075153006497925230\lib\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.5.1-tests.jar]: it still exists.
14/10/31 13:52:31 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\tmp\hadoop-Kenny\hadoop-unjar2075153006497925230\lib\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.5.1.jar]: it still exists.
14/10/31 13:52:31 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\tmp\hadoop-Kenny\hadoop-unjar2075153006497925230\lib\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.5.1.jar]: it still exists.
```

I've heard that problems similar to this may be caused because environmental variables have not been set correctly, so I've added this to the beginning of hadoop-env.cmd:

```
set HADOOP_PREFIX=C:\hadoop\hadoop-2.5.1
set HADOOP_HOME=%HADOOP_PREFIX%
set HADOOP_CONF_DIR=%HADOOP_PREFIX%\etc\hadoop
set YARN_CONF_DIR=%HADOOP_CONF_DIR%
set PATH=%PATH%;%HADOOP_PREFIX%\bin
```

I've also manually set these variables prior to running the command, but the same error still occurs. Does anyone know what my problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command...
Mean while you are refering the java_home path it's failing...

try something like -> C:\Progra~1\
instead of using -> C:\Program Files

Even then also I believe it will throw native library exception..b'coz it won't be able to get the winutils.exe and hadoop.dll files in bin folder